# How to add matplotlib object to Bokeh layout?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I am working on a tab-based local Bokeh application, and I am trying to include a matplotlib object in the first tab of this app.

The object is a Venn Diagram, which is outside of the scope of Bokeh.

So far, I have got something like this:

```py
import bokeh
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2

output_file('test.html')

scatter = figure(plot_width = 900, plot_height = 400)

scatter.circle([1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,5,7,9,11,16], size = 12, alpha = 0.6)

bar = figure(plot_width = 450, plot_height = 400)

bar.quad(top = [3,5,7,9,11,16], bottom = 0, left = [1,2,3,4,5,6], right = [1.9,2.9,3.9,4.9,5.9,6.9])

venn2([set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']), set(['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'])])

plots = column(scatter, bar)

show(plots)
```

Ideally, I would like to position the Venn diagram in the manner shown below.

[image: desired layout of resulting Panel object]

I somewhat naïvely thought something like `column(scatter, row(bar, plt.show()))` would work, but it does not.

I'm relatively new to Python and I have never used MatPlotLib before.

Comment: perhaps you could export the mpl plot into a `io.BytesIO` as a png, read it with `PIL` and plot using an image or image_rgb ([documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.image))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment: there is not any built-in integration between Bokeh and MPL. If you to embed an MPL plot in some Bokeh content, I can think of two approaches:

- If you an convert to a file format, e.g PNG, and host the image file somwhere accessible via URL, then you could use an HTML `<img>` tag in Bokeh `Div` to display the image file.
- Otherwise, use PIL or some other tool to generate a NumPy of RGBA data for the image of the MPL plot. Then you can "plot" the MPL plot in a Bokeh plot using the `ImageRGBA` glyph, as suggested in the comment.

  ```
  # Just some synthetic RGBA data
  img = np.empty((20,20), dtype=np.uint32)
  view = img.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((N, N, 4))
  for i in range(N):
      for j in range(N):
          view[i, j, 0] = int(i/N*255)
          view[i, j, 1] = 158
          view[i, j, 2] = int(j/N*255)
          view[i, j, 3] = 255

  p = figure()

  # must give a vector of images
  p.image_rgba(image=[img], x=0, y=0, dw=10, dh=10)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/set_operations.html), which uses Bokeh/Holoviews as a plotting backend. The above link shows how to create Venn-Diagrams based on Set-Operations (Circles).